# Different android design style for different Android OS versions

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

Sorry for the newbie question. I'm developing Android app using Xamarin studio and MonoDroid.
If I'm choosing target platform v2.3 then I have support for devices running Andoird OS v2.3+

but... for devices running v2.3 I have the same design as for devices running v4.0.3:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19503836/android_api10.png

Only if I choose project target platform v4.0.3 then I get expected design but in this case I have no support for devices running v2.3:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19503836/android_api15.png

Is it possible to have different design style activated for different Android OS versions having target platform v2.3?

Answer (score 1):

You can use different layouts for different android versions. Just make different folders for the layouts. Res/layout is for default layouts, Res/layout-v14 is for android 4.3 and above. Just look for the API version you need and add it to the folder name.

You can also use different styles per version the same way. The styles are defined in a XML on res/values, just specify the API version in the folder res/values-vXX.

By your example it seems that by default your IDE is already creating different styiles for different versions, so look for that folders on your project tree.

You have more info on [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

Comment: eventually monodroid projects has the only UI file and it displayed in different ways for different targeted platforms.